# Conditional expectation given past equals zero implies covariance of zero?

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales, covariance

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be random variables on a common probability space (define $X_0 := 0$).

I'd really like the following proposition to be true (and I think that it is) but I'm not sure how to prove it: for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$,

> $$ \text{  }\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1} | X_1, ..., X_n) = 0   \implies \mathbb{E}(X_i) = Cov(X_i, X_j) = 0
> > \text{ for any } i \neq j $$

I suspect that this proof will rest upon some iterated use of the tower property of conditional expectation or some nice property of conditional expectation when conditioning on multiple random variables that I'm not aware of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1 \leq i \leq n$, $E(X_iX_{n+1}|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=X_iE(X_{n+1}|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=0$. Take expectation on both sides  and finish the proof.

Comment: Okay so let $i < j$ then we have $Cov(X_i, X_j) = \mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) - \mathbb{E}(X_i) \mathbb{E}(X_j) = - \mathbb{E}(X_i) \mathbb{E}(X_j)$ since the first term vanishes (due to your comment). I'm unsure of how to handle this term now...

Comment: If you take expectation in the given equation you get $EX_{n+1}=0$  for all $n$ right?

Comment: ohhhh yes indeed! Thank you so much!